# why success function is never called and how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express, post

when i try and do the post, the data is send and the server receives it but the success function is never called. The connection appears in the network inspector tab of chrome as stalled and, a warning: connection is not finished yet.

**script:**

```
var modif = {
    CRN: $("#DIAS").parent().parent().parent().children()[0].children[0].innerText,
    DIAS: $("#DIAS").val(),
    start_hr: $("#STRHR").val(),
    end_hr: $("#ENDHR").val(),
    title: $("#TITLE").val()
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/cmanager/edit',   
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'POST',
    data: modif,
    success: function (order) {
        alert("functiono!");
    },
    error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " +
          "error thrown: " + errorThrown
    );
```

**server:**

```
app.post("/cmanager/edit",function (req, res) {
var CRN = req.body.CRN;
var DIAS = req.body.DIAS;
var start_hr = req.body.start_hr;
var end_hr = req.body.end_hr;
var title = req.body.title;
console.log(CRN);
console.log(DIAS);
console.log(start_hr);
console.log(end_hr);
console.log(title);
var usrq = "update section natural join class set DIAS = '"+DIAS+"', start_hr = '"+start_hr+"', end_hr = '"+end_hr+"', title = '"+title+"' where CRN = '"+CRN+"';";
  connection.query(usrq, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) 
    console.log(error.code);
    else
    try {
        console.log("hello");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("bad ifo by client");
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: You have a typo. Should be `success` not `succes`.

Comment: @Li357 It's a small thing, but post it as an answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: thanks, sorry about that. still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in your server are you actually sending any data back to the client.

In your server, you need to call `res.end()` at a minimum.  It looks to me what you actually want is `res.sendStatus(204);`.

Also note that you are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and you will be hacked if you haven't been already.  Always use parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: thanks! definitely will take care of the SQL security.